# How to create multiple profiles in OS X Mail (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, apple-mail, osx-yosemite

Is it possible create multiple profiles in OS X Mail, with specific mail accounts, and switch between them?  I am responsible for 30+ different mail accounts (accessed via IMAP).  It is distracting having Mail access all of them throughout the day.  I would like to keep one set of mail accounts open (one or two accounts), for day-to-day operations, and then open and "admin" set of accounts when needed.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you could do is create a system user per account and inside this username configure the mail account.

Under `System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Options`, you could enable `Show fast user switching menu as` and then will be able to have fast access between usernames/accounts.

Comment: Thought about doing this.  Just seemed disappointing.  i was hoping I was just missing something obvious where I could do it more... properly?  elegantly?